# Plotting columns x and y of pandas dataframe with third column value determining the shape of the points

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have this requirement. I have a sample data in a text file containing 3 attributes per line. Test1 score, Test2 score and pass or fail represented as 1 or 0. 
example:-

```
 Score1 Score2 Result
 35.00 55.00 0
 45.00 34.00 0
 50.00 75.00 0
 80.00 80.00 1
 55.00 85.00 1
 67.03 66.03 0
 ..
 ..
```

Now I am trying to plot Score1 against X-axis and Score2 against Y-axis , but I want to represent pass (1) as '+' while fail (0) as 'o' when I plot the points and in different colors ( for example '+' in green while 'o' in red)

I wrote the code below as follows:-

```
 pos=y[y==1]
 neg=y[y==0]
 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')

 ax=X.plot(kind='scatter',x='Score1',y='Score2',s=pos*10,color='DarkGreen', label='Pass');        
 X.plot(kind='scatter', x='Score1', y='Score2', s=neg*200, color='Red',   label='Fail',ax=ax);
```

I am not sure if this right as I can only see the plot for pass result but not the color I am asking for while my fail result does not get plotted. 
what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
pos=y[y.Result==1]
neg=y[y.Result==0]

ax=pos.plot(kind='scatter',
            x='Score1',
            y='Score2',
            s=100,
            color='DarkGreen', 
            label='Pass', 
            marker='+')    

neg.plot(kind='scatter', 
         x='Score1', 
         y='Score2', 
         s=50, 
         color='Red',  
         label='Fail',
         marker='o',
         ax=ax)

patches, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(patches, labels, loc='upper left', scatterpoints=1)
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thanks. I should have told you that Y is a series. But I used your code on X itself and worked. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary to define the markers per result type
Use `groupby` to iterate through types

```
m = {0: 'o', 1: '+'}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
for n, g in X.groupby('Result'):
    g.plot.scatter(
        'Score1', 'Score2', marker=m[n], ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: appreciate your response. How do I get the color set right with your sample code?

Comment: @sunny use the same trick I used for marker. Use the parameter color.